# PDA and CFG of language of regular expressions

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata

I am stuck on a problem involving PDA's and CFG's. The problem is as stated:

> Give a CFG and a PDA for the language of regular expressions over the
>   alphabet $\{a, b, c\}$. Give the formal tuple definition of each. You may use the 
>   shorthand for pushing a string in the state diagram of your PDA, but not in the 
>   tuple form. It will help if you expand out the shorthand in the state diagram. 
>   To avoid ambiguity, use the symbols $($, $)$, $λ$ for the language.  The alphabet should 
>   be $\{a, b, c,(,), +, λ,∗ \}$. For brevity, you can define $δ$ by giving its output on 
>   the inputs that don’t return $∅$. Something like $δ(x_1) = y_1; δ(x_2) = y_2;$

My first attempt at it got me stuck after defining the Context Free Grammar and the PDA. I am having trouble understanding how this grammar could, for instance,

- Derive $(a + b)^*(c + λ)a^*$
- Make a PDA for this.

How can I make a PDA for this? How can I make a CFG for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you've constructed a grammar, what's the problem with showing that your grammar produces the required string? And then there are standard algorithms for converting CFGs to PDAs.

Comment: The analogous problem for arithmetic expressions is commonly presented in introductory texts. I suggest you find one and (slightly) modify it for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  Let us assume an alphabet $\Sigma$. Now, the following are regular expressions (at least according to some textbooks):

- $a$ is a regular expression, if $a \in \Sigma$
- $\emptyset$ is a regular expression
- $r_1 \cup r_2$ is a regular expression, if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are regular expressions
- $r_1 \circ r_2$ is a regular expression, if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are regular expressions
- Nothing else is a regular expression.

How can you summarize these formation rules as a collection of context-free production rules where $r$ is a nonterminal?